# JavaFX - GridPane row increases in height after inserting a picture into a button

Tags: button, javafx, imageview, gridpane

I have a gridpane of buttons. When I click on a button an ImageView is inserted into it and for some reason the cell height increases. I can't understand why and how can I fix it. How to make cell size constant?

[image]

after button click the first row height increases.

[image]

My Controller class:

```
public class Controller {
    public GridPane gameTable;
    public Label score1;
    public Label score2;
    Image openImage = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/open.jpg"));
    MyButton open1;
    MyButton open2;
    Player player1 = new Player();
    Player player2 = new Player();
    Player currentPlayer = player1;

    public void initialize(){
        System.out.println(gameTable.getRowCount()+" "+gameTable.getColumnCount());
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

                MyButton btn = new MyButton(i);
                btn.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                btn.setMaxHeight(100);
                gameTable.add(btn, i, j);
                btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

                        ImageView iv = new ImageView(openImage);
                        iv.setPreserveRatio(true);
                        iv.setFitWidth(btn.getWidth()-10);
                        btn.setGraphic(iv);


                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behavior of a `GridPane` is to try to size all the cells to the preferred size of their content. (If there's extra space available, it'll try to allocate it evenly, or according to constraints set on the nodes or row or column constraints.) When you add the image to the button, you increase the button's preferred height, so you increase the space allocated to the cell containing that button.

You can change the default behavior by setting `RowConstraints` on the `GridPane` (to change how vertical space is allocated to each row) and `ColumnConstraints` (to control horizontal space allocated to each column).

If you want to fully constraint the height of each row, set the `min`, `pref`, and `maxHeight` of all rows:

```
for (int j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j++) {
    RowConstraints rc = new RowConstraints();
    rc.setMinHeight(100);
    rc.setPrefHeight(100);
    rc.setMaxHeight(100);
    gameTable.getRowConstraints().add(rc);
}
```

If you want to set the heights proportionally, use `setPercentHeight()`:

```
for (int j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j++) {
    RowConstraints rc = new RowConstraints();
    rc.setPercentHeight(100.0 / 5);
    gameTable.getRowConstraints().add(rc);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem the only part of the issue. For columns this seems to be done already, however the `Button` that contains the image seems to be larger than the cell bounds (as indicated by the focus color behind part of button (1,0) and by the fact that there's no rounded border on the right of the button). It's necessary to play around with the insets for the button graphic. Additionaly choose a large enough image and the layout will be back to being broken again(; try this with 2 wallpaper-sized images).